# How do I query the state of a contract at a given block number given the deprecation of contracts_getStorage?

Tags: rpc, contracts

The [previous answer](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/3456/can-you-query-the-state-of-a-contract-at-a-given-block-number) is now incorrect due to the [deprecation of the RPCs](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/12358).

How do we query the historic contract state now?

In the PR comment it states:

> The high level contracts API in polkadot.js already uses state_call so upgrading to the latest version here is enough. If you are using api.rpc.contracts directly you need to switch to api.call.contractsApi.

However, switching to `api.rx.call.contractsApi.call` does not give an option to pass `at`. There is the option to create an instance of the api at a specific block but there is no explanation of how to query contracts using this.

The following does not work as the returned type of `api.at` (`ApiDecoration<"promise">`) is not equivalent to `ApiPromise`

```
        if (atBlock) {
            const atApi = atBlock ? await api.at(atBlock) : api
            contract = new ContractPromise(atApi, abi, contractAddress)
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

To access historic contract state you do not need a `ContractPromise`. It will not construct using the `at` API. Instead, you need to replicate the [calls made in the polkadot-js/api package](https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/blob/b21cc0ae0641e10a8569aef6107b6c1701929704/packages/api-contract/src/base/Contract.ts#L141-L151) using your `at` API.

e.g.

```
        // choose either the existing api or a historic api
        let api: ApiBase<'promise'> | ApiDecoration<'promise'> = this.api
        if (atBlock) {
            api = atBlock ? await this.api.at(atBlock) : this.api
        }

        // Make the call to the contracts API, specifying the contract address
        // This next part is copied from polkadot-js packages/api-contract/src/base/Contract.ts
        const responseObservable = api.rx.call.contractsApi
            .call<ContractExecResult>(
                callerAddress,
                this.contract.address,
                callParams.value,
                callParams.gasLimit,
                null, //storageDepositLimit
                methodObj.toU8a(encodedArgs)
            )
            .pipe(
                map(
                    ({ debugMessage, gasConsumed, gasRequired, result, storageDeposit }): ContractCallOutcome => ({
                        debugMessage,
                        gasConsumed,
                        gasRequired:
                            gasRequired && !convertWeight(gasRequired).v1Weight.isZero() ? gasRequired : gasConsumed,
                        output:
                            result.isOk && methodObj.returnType
                                ? this.contract.abi.registry.createTypeUnsafe(
                                      methodObj.returnType.lookupName || methodObj.returnType.type,
                                      [result.asOk.data.toU8a(true)],
                                      { isPedantic: true }
                                  )
                                : null,
                        result,
                        storageDeposit,
                    })
                )
            )
        const response = await firstValueFrom(responseObservable)
```